# Authentication without database ( PHP )

Tags: php, authentication

How to securely authenticate a user without using any type of database.

```
authenticate.php?username={$_GET['username']}&password={$_GET['password']}


if ($_GET['username'] == "secret_username" && password == "secret_password")
{
   $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
   header("Location: password_protected_page.php");
   exit;
}
```

This method seems to be an option. Is it secure?

Comment: Passed as GET arguments, so visible in your address bar, you might as well not bother

Comment: Security evaluation usually requires a broader list of pros and cons, not a code rubber stamp. Therefore is a bit too broad.

Comment: So what if a I use POST arguments?

Comment: Labeling POST requests inherently more "secure" than GET params is an incorrect assumption. They don't leave log and proxy trails as easily, but are just as easy to capture over non-SSL connections.

Comment: At least POST args aren't visible to a "man looking over your shoulder" attack, or a "man looking through your browser history" attack

Comment: @MarkBaker So what do you prefer for authentication without a db?

Comment: @Anonymous - filesystem would be a replacement for a db for storing username/password (as long as its outside of the web root), and hashed (using password_hash() in case anybody does get hold of the file), or even an SQLite database (if you don't want a full MySQL or Postgres or whatever database); but always use SSL, for client/server communication (that's nothing to do with whether the password is stored in a db or not), and I'll always use POST rather than GET

Comment: Security is somewhat relative.  I hope the authentication for the DoD's missile defense system is more secure than this, or even my local bank.  But for instance, the default APC stats page uses something similar: http://git.php.net/?p=pecl/caching/apc.git;a=blob_plain;f=apc.php;hb=HEAD They use HTTP Basic Auth, which puts the authentication details in $_SERVER, instead of $_GET or $_POST, but the user and pass are stored in plain text as constants inside the file.  This is not 100% unhackable (nothing is), but it does mean you can put the file in your web root, without it being wide open.

Comment: Are you using Apache, and can you use .htaccess files? You can just use HTAuth so that Apache authenticates the password, and then use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` to access the authenticated user. It's not ultra secure, but it's far safer than what you're trying here. Take a look at: http://www.web2generators.com/apache-tools/htpasswd-generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a file to hold your data.
have a users.txt below your public html like so:

`username:hashedpassword`

then you use `fopen`

```
<?php

    $filename = "/home/users.txt";
    $file = fopen( $filename, "r" );
    $display = fread( $file, filesize( $filename ) );
    fclose($file);

?>
```

Then explode it by newline and then |, then check if the first is equal to username and the second is equal to md5(password).

Seems like the easiest way to me...

Comment: I guess I didn't look at your question as much as I should have, I would use GET and i'd definately hash the password no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

I would at least post for authentication but otherwise it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, you can do that. But, just use POST.

There is nothing wrong with the process. Even when we use database, we actually do the same thing but just using some select command.

You might be thinking about password hash, but they are used so that, even if the 3rd party gets a hold of database dump(somehow), they can never actually decrypt the password, as hash are one way function. Now in you case you are not using database, so that's not a problem.

However the problem lies in scalability. Are you sure that there will always be just one user of the system. If yes, then its okay, else go for DB.

Answer (score 0):

I learned PHP on my own. I never took a course nor had a mentor.  I had issues "getting" datasbase calls, as they seemed so convoluted compared to other PHP which seemed natural. I started using this a long time ago.

You can create a text file (username.php) in a directory OFF the web server accesible folders.

(consider permissions!)

So you have /root/users and in that folder you have (by username)

```
/root/users.Joe.php
/root/users/Juan.php
/root/users/Tim.php
```

Tim.php contents

```
<?php
$userpath='/var/www/html/users/Tim';
$password='Timspassword';
?>
```

Now when Tim logs on wee have code that does this:

```
<?php
include '/root/users/'.$_POST[username].'.php';
if ($password == $_POST['password']) 
{
$_SESSION['loggedin']='yes';
$_SESSION['expire']='<how much time you need?>';
}
?>
```

This way you can more easily create new users . BTW I use an index.php in each users folder that will do very little if not logged in as that particular user that matches the name of the folder. You should also use https. You could also use password encryption/decryption in these user passwords.

Truth be told, Database injection is a real vulberability. Daily I get hackers looking for databases on my sites. THERE ARE NONE, so they go away.

no databese required.